# Check while iterating through an array that certain "divider elements" are regularly spaced?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, iteration

I'm having trouble coming up with the efficient algorithm that must exist for this problem:

Iterate through an array checking for elements which are "markers". Set a flag if I notice any marker that doesn't divide the rest of the elements into runs of the same length. Except the final run, which is the remainder.

Example that shouldn't set the flag:

```
*....*....*..*
```

Examples that should set the flag:

```
*....*...*...*
*....*....**
```

Intuition says it should be possible to do online pretty trivially and that it's probably equivalent to some well-known problem whose usual name I don't know.

Comment: Can you just iterate and store the length of the current run and previous. Then you encounter marker you compare these lengths - they should always be equal except for the end of the string.

Comment: I think so but I'm trying that and can't nail it. If the first divider is not the first element that should also set the flag. Also some elements won't have any dividers and shouldn't set the flag. I didn't want to bog down the question too much if all the details weren't key. But maybe it's only the details that are making it tricky for me to get right.

Comment: It could be that this is more about implementation that about algorithms. Let me know if it might better belong on the code golf SE.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the efficient way would be a tiny state machine ...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Count the numbers of elements between markers and form a list. Than check if this lists elements are all the same excluding last one and that last element of the list is not 0. *Edge case: only one element, it can be 0.*

**Python code:**

```
def is_correct(string):
    splitted_list = string.split("*")[1:-1]  # Split and strip edge elements.
    if len(splitted_list) == 1:
        return True
    if len(splitted_list[-1]) == 0:   # Check that last element is 0.
        return False
    for i in range(1, len(splitted_list)-1):   # Check that others are the same.
        if len(splitted_list[0]) != len(splitted_list[i]):
            return False
    return True  

# Test    
print is_correct("*....*....*..*")
print is_correct("*....*...*...*")
print is_correct("*....*....**")
```

Comment: Yes I actually think this is the easier to implement but less efficient way, and was going to mention it in the question but it kept turning into a wall of text so I left it all out. Anyway, intuitively I think it ought to be possible with just a few variables. I'm going to use the list approach but continue to think about the non-list approach as it's become an interesting coding exercise and puzzle for me now.

Comment: The difference between both approaches will at best be minimal. My code runs in O(n), where n is length of string. This can't be improved lower from O(n), at bets you might trim a constant a little bit.

Comment: Well I iterate over the array once already so the logic can be called from that iteration with a callback etc rather than doing an additional iteration and would also work with lazy/inline. I think I mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to first calculate the expected length based on the first `*xyz*` occurrence. Once this is known we know where to expect the remaining dividers (`*`). If the divider is encountered out of place it is illegal unless it's part of the remainder.

It's essentially the same logic as in Riko's answer, but with a lot more code as calculating the segment sizes is done inline instead of with string.split.

Below is an example in JavaScript. I tried keeping it as simple as possible by staying away from the more functional aspects of JavaScript. Unfortunately this made it a bit of a wall of code.

```js
var isCorrect = function( str, divider ) {

    process.stdout.write( str + ': ' );

    // First check the obvious cases. These allow us to skip these checks
    // within the loop.
    if( str[0] !== divider )
        return "Doesn't start with divider";
    if( str[ str.length - 1 ] !== divider )
        return "Doesnt' end with divider";

    // Two variables to hold the state.
    // The second variable (divisions) is required only if we want to make
    // sure that the last segment is "optimal".
    var division = null;
    var divisions = 0;

    // First find the first divider.
    var i = 1;
    for( ; i < str.length; i++ ) {
        if( str[i] === divider ) {
            division = i;
            divisions++;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Now that we know the division length, make sure the dividers
    // are in expected positions.
    for( ; i < str.length; i++ ) {

        var expectedDivider = ( (i) % division === 0 );

        // See if we are expecting a divider.
        if( expectedDivider ) {
            if( str[i] !== divider )
                return "Expected divider at position " + i;
            divisions++;
            continue;
        }

        // Since we are not expecting a divider, make sure we don't have one.
        if( str[i] === divider ) {

            // We had a divider in an unexpected place. This is only allowed for
            // the last segment.
            if( i < str.length - 1 )
                return "Divider not expected at position " + i;

            // This is last segment. We could return 'ok' here unless we want
            // the optimal segments.

            // For optimal segments we want to know whether the last segment
            // could have "borrowed" items from the previous ones while still
            // remaining smaller than the rest.

            // Calculate the bits missing from the last segment.
            var offset = ( (i-1) % division );
            var missing = division - offset - 1;

            if( offset === 0 )
                return "Empty division at the end";

            // Could the missing bits be taken from the previous divisions?
            if( missing > divisions )
                return "Last division too short";

            // Last segment was OK.
            return "ok";
        }
    }

    // All divisions were in expected places:
    // Last segment was as long as the rest.
    return "ok";
};
```

The test cases I used:

```js
// Simple cases

// OK
console.log( isCorrect( '*--*--*--*', '*' ) );
console.log( isCorrect( '*---*---*---*', '*' ) );
console.log( isCorrect( '*---*---*--*', '*' ) );

// Middle segment too short.
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*----*-----*', '*' ) );

// First segment too short
console.log( isCorrect( '*----*-----*-----*', '*' ) );

// "Optimality" tests

// In "optimal" division the segments could be divided to three with
// *----*----*---* so *-----*-----*-* is "unoptimal"
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*-*', '*' ) );

// These are "optimal"
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*--*', '*' ) );
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*---*', '*' ) );
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*----*', '*' ) );
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*-----*', '*' ) );

// Last segment too long
console.log( isCorrect( '*-----*-----*------*', '*' ) );

// Last segment empty
console.log( isCorrect( '*--*--*--*--*--**', '*' ) );
```

Comment: The last segment does have to be "optimal". I realize now that I didn't make that clear in the question. I'm analysing your answer slowly partly because my brain is a bit friend and partly in case I still left anything unclear in my question. Thanks for taking a look and I'll vote/accept when I've gone through it. (-:

Comment: I've been going over some of my real world data and found that I did misstate the problem. I'm thinking I should probably ask a new question since there are already answers here. The specific version of the problem I'm doing is balancing columns so rather than a final column which can have any length equal to or less than the preceding columns I can have one or more final columns but they can only have one less than column #1.